# Collectives: Members table is truncated on small viewports

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

I browsed to the [members tab of the Microsoft Azure collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure?tab=members) on my iPhone 11 using Safari on iOS 16.3 and see that the members table is truncated in both portrait and landscape orientations:

[image: Members tab with truncated table]

This only happens on first render. If I switch browser tab to another and back again, the table is re-rendered correctly.

Comment: It seems [so] doesn't support Safari on iOS 16.3 according to: https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/

Comment: `if (User.IsFormerEmployee) { showFullData = false; }`

Comment: Confirmed it looks the same in Chrome on iOS as well, even though the emulator on Chrome desktop does not cut things off. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix was released in February 2023.